# Regex to match the nth (n > 1) occurrence of the same word

Tags: regex

I would like a regular expression that can match the nth (n > 1) occurrence of the same word in a text. I need this to detect repeating words in a text.

Example: *"one two three **one** ten nine six **one** five **ten**"* 
( {'one','one','ten'} should be detected).

I found several examples on how to detect repeating occurrences of a given pattern. This question is different because we don't know in advance what word(s) would be repeating. Is this even possible with regex?

Comment: Why use regex for this instead of something like a map of words to their count?

Comment: Have you tried split() and a collections.Counter()?

Comment: Lookbehind should be able to do this, but it depends on your regex flavour (used tool / programming language) how much is available. It's probably easier to filter the matched words manually (without regex)

Comment: @Dave Newton Testing the limits of regex :)

Comment: @sln: Thanks. Edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, regular expressions cannot do this. However, most “regular expression” engines support backreferences (strictly speaking, something regular expressions cannot do), which would allow you to match such things, e.g.:

```
\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b
```

…would match in several different places, with the first capture containing the repeated word.

Comment: Actually backreferences still make a regular language (on finite input alphabets), but with a huge load of syntactic sugar.

Comment: @icktoofay I tried your answer: https://regex101.com/r/qC7oN4/1. Sorry, I probably missed something, but it doesn't appear to work correctly. Or is it supposed to detect only one repeating word at a time?

Comment: @user1566515: If you make it find all possible matches, including overlapping matches, it will find them all. Unfortunately it looks like that web site only finds non-overlapping matches.

Comment: @icktoofay Actually, that's not a problem for my use case. Thanks a lot!